# Under what circumstances do close-votes generate downvotes, if any?

Tags: discussion, downvoting

I'm asking in relation to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516445/chrome-on-ubuntu-youtube-crashing)... but I think this could be a good general purpose answer.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238360/213575

Comment: i see the point, but i'm looking for an atomic answer.

Comment: Thats why I only said "related"